# Detection of an empty set in PLPGSQL FOR loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql, postgresql-12

Is there any way to detect that set returned by a query in Postgres is empty?

Namely:

```
FOR varname IN
   select testvar from foo
LOOP
   <do some stuff on the set>
END LOOP;
-- Loop finished or Set was EMPTY
IF NOT FOUND ?????   THEN
    <do some other stuff for empty set>
END IF;
```

Of course I can run the query prior to the loop and use the `NOT FOUND` or introduce a counter and then check if it was `0` at the end of the loop but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid that.

(May be more appropriate for dba.SE but starting here)

Comment: Yes. Just remove `?????`.

Comment: @klin - you have true, I checked it in source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only buildin solution, then you should to use `FOUND` variable. It is `true` when the result was not empty or `false` when result is empty. It is safe, and the value doesn't depend on statements in cycle's body.